# How does scanr work? Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

I have been messing with some Haskell functions, some I have understand and some don't.

For example if we do: `scanl (+) 0 [1..3]` my understanding is the following:

```
1. the accumulator is 0                  acc         = 0    |
2. (+) applied to acc and first el       acc = 0 + 1 = 1    |
3. (+) applied to latest acc and snd el  acc = 1 + 2 = 3    |
4. (+) applied to latest acc and third   acc = 3 + 3 = 6    V
```

Now when we make the list we get `[0, 1, 3, 6]`.

But I can't seem to understand how does `scanr (+) 0 [1..3]` gives me: `[6,5,3,0]`
Maybe `scanr` works the following way?

```
1. the first element in the list is the sum of all other + acc
2. the second element is the sum from right to left (<-) of the last 2 elements
3. the third element is the sum of first 2...
```

I don't see if that's the pattern or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`scanr` is to `foldr` what `scanl` is to `foldl`. `foldr` works from the right:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3] =
  (1 + (2 + (3 +   0))) =
  (1 + (2 +    3)) =
  (1 +    5) =
     6
-- [ 6,   5,   3,   0 ]
```

and `scanr` just shows the interim results in sequence: `[6,5,3,0]`. It could be defined as

```
scanr (+) z xs = foldr g [z] xs
  where
  g x ys@(y:_) = x+y : ys
```

`scanl` though should work like

```
scanl (+) 0 [1,2,3] =
  0 : scanl (+) (0+1) [2,3] =
  0 : 1 : scanl (+) (1+2) [3] =
  0 : 1 : 3 : scanl (+) (3+3) [] =
  0 : 1 : 3 : [6]
```

so it must be that

```
scanl (+) z xs = foldr f h xs z
   where h      z = [z]
         f x ys z = z : ys (z + x)
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanl` and `scanr` are used to show the value of the accumulator on each iteration. `scanl` iterates from left-to-right, and `scanr` from right-to-left.

Consider the following example:

```hs
scanl (+) 0 [1, 2, 3]

-- 0. `scanl` stores 0 as the accumulator and in the output list [0]
-- 1. `scanl` adds 0 and 1 and stores 1 as the accumulator and in the output list [0, 1]
-- 2. `scanl` adds 1 and 2 and stores 3 as the accumulator and in the output list [0, 1, 3]
-- 3. `scanl` adds 3 and 3 and stores 6 as the accumulator and in the output list [0, 1, 3, 6]
-- 4. `scanl` returns the output list [0, 1, 3, 6]
```

As you can see, `scanl` stores the results of the accumulator while it's iterating through the list. This is the same for `scanr`, but the list is iterated in reverse.

Here's another example:

```hs
scanl (flip (:)) [] [1, 2, 3]

-- [[], [1], [2,1], [3,2,1]]

scanr       (:)  [] [1, 2, 3]

-- [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []]
```